# Quick and elegant explanation of $B^T A B x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$ with $A$ symmetric and $\mathcal R(B) = \mathcal R(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

I am finalizing the proof of the spectral theorem and I have to motivate the fact that if $A \in \mathbb R ^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and the columns of $B \in \mathbb R ^{n\times p}$, with $p < n$, make up an orthonormal base of $\mathcal N^\perp (A)$, then the matrix product 
$$B^T AB x = 0$$ with $x \in \mathbb R ^{p}$, can be satisfied iff $x = 0$.

Since $A = A^T$, $\mathcal N ^{\perp} (A) = \mathcal R  (A^T) =  \mathcal R  (A)$ so the range and the kernel of $A$ are orthogonal and necessarily $\mathcal R  (B) = \mathcal R(A)$.

It seems I am stuck in providing a quick explanation for the necessity of $x = 0$.

Comment: Isn't there a way to decompose $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition).

Comment: @drhab. Unfortunately I am trying to prove exactly that a symmetric matrix is always similar to a diagonal matrix via an orthogonal matrix, therefore I cannot use this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by $\mathcal{N}(A)$ you mean $\mathrm{ker}A$ and by $\mathcal{N}^{\perp}(A)$ you mean the choice of some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathcal{N}^{\perp}(A)$ and $\mathcal{N}(A)$ are orthogonal and $\mathcal{N}(A) \oplus \mathcal{N}^{\perp}(A) = \mathbb{R}^n$.

In this case, by definition, $AB \colon \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is injective and $\mathrm{im}(AB)= \mathrm{im}(A)$. It also follows $\mathrm{rk}(AB)=p$.

Therefore, also $p= \mathrm{rk}((AB)^T)= \mathrm{rk}(B^TA^T)= \mathrm{rk}(B^T A)$. But this means, that $B^T_{|\mathrm{im}(A)} = B^T_{|\mathrm{im}(AB)} $ is an isomorphism which in implies that $B^T A B$ is injective.

Because the proof was deemed too long, here the short version without the unnecessary details:

The map $AB$ is injective and $\mathrm{im}(AB)=\mathrm{im}(A)$. Thus, $p = \mathrm{rk}((AB)^T)= \mathrm{rk}(B^TA) = \mathrm{rk}(B^T A B)$.

Comment: I mean "null space" of the matrix $A$, which is the same as the kernel of the linear map the matrix is associated to, of course, so yes.
I don't get the notation $B^T_{|\mathrm {im}(A)}$, what does this mean?

Comment: The linear map defined by $B^T$ restricted to the subspace given by the image of the linear map defined by $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. To be honest, I was looking for a slightly quicker proof.

Comment: This proof is two lines. I don't think it gets a lot quicker (and more elementary) than that.

Comment: I edited the proof above, so that it contains a one line version which has all the necessary parts of the proof.

Comment: I don't consider your answer too long, only I needed something more succinct. Let me just get it straight. Is $AB$ injective because $B$ is square and full rank? Is $\mathrm{rk} (B^T A) = \mathrm{rk} (B^T A B)$  for the same reason?

Comment: $AB$ is injective, because a) $B$ is injective (it is rank $p$) and b) the image of $B$ is just $\mathcal{N}^{\perp}(A)$, which by definition is disjoint from the kernel of $A$.

Comment: About the rank: just see the rank as the dimension of the image of the maps defined by $B^TA$ and $B^TAB$. Let $v \in \mathrm{im}(B^TA)$ and $w$ with $B^TAw=v$. Now take $w'$ with $ABw'=Aw$ (this is possible, because $\mathrm{rk}(AB)=\mathrm{rk}(A)$, so every vector in the image of $A$ is already in the image of $AB$). Then $B^TABw'=v$ and we see $\mathrm{im}(B^TAB)=\mathrm{im}(B^TA)$.